# how to make annotation text in two lines instead of one line which cross chart in case text is long?

Tags: asp.net, annotations, mschart

I am using asp.net 3.5 chart control and for showing message when there is no data present . I have used this method

```
 if (dsAllDepartment.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.TextAnnotation annotation =
                new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.TextAnnotation();

                annotation.Text =ddldepartment.SelectedItem.Text+"  विभाग के लिए  डाटा उपलब्ध नहीं है";
                annotation.X = 5;
                annotation.Y = 25;
                annotation.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12);
                annotation.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                chAllDepartmentAllActivity.Annotations.Add(annotation);           
            }
```

its working but problem is when text too long its cross the chart instead of appearing in two lines ...

[image: chart where annotations cross chart]

Comment: If you are OK with explicit line breaks in your text, try inserting `/n` in "strategic" places; I think it will help.

Comment: /n apperaing as it is , its not making a line breaking..

Comment: OH ITS WORKS INSTEAD OF /n I USED THIS  \n AND ITS WORKS :)

Comment: YOU CAN PUT YOUR COMMENT AS ANSWER ALSO SO IT CAN HELP OTHER PEOPLES ALSO .... AND I CAN ACCEPT YOUR ANSWER

Comment: Sorry about the typo above; added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with explicit line breaks in your text, try inserting `\n` in "strategic" places. This way you will at least be able to control your manually written text.